# How to define the screen hue/color after AlertDialog shown?

Tags: android, colors, android-alertdialog

When AlertDialog is being shown, the whole screen hue/color changes. Is it somehow possible to define to which color should it be changed? Below are screens - before and after AlertDialog appears.

*Before:*

[image: sreen before AlertDialog appears]

*After:*

[image: screen after AlertDialog appears]

You can see that the screen color changed.

What I noticed it looks like it is not the color change, but just all colors are becoming **darker**. Can I somehow define how this change should work like?

Answer (score 1):

It could be because [`FLAG_DIM_BEHIND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_DIM_BEHIND) is set on your dialog window.

In that case you can remove it with the clear flags method:
`dialogWindow.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)`

One quick way to check which flags are set on your window is to check the  `mAttrs`-field on your window  in `adb shell dumpsys window windows`.

Comment: It helps in a way that after this command the color of background does not change in any way - colors are not becoming darker. I wonder if it is somehow possible to define how this color should be changing.
For those who can't acces dialogWindow - you can get this by **alertDialog.getWindow()**

Comment: Yes it is possible to set the android:windowBackground on the dialog via the dialogs style.